How to set BLANK in IF statement in excel
I just want a simple IF(condition,BLANK) that can be picked up by ISBLANK().
I tried the "", it does set it seemingly blank, but when I chain it with a ISBLANK() on that "" cell, it returns FALSE. Is there a way where I can set it so that ISBLANK will detect the output being BLANK?

The cell is not blank due to the formula.
But you can check the length of the cell value:
=LEN(B1)=0
where B1 contains the IF-formula
